# Is it possible to mirror my MacBookPro's screen to my iMac?

Tags: imac, mirroring

Both are using the latest Mojave. And I'd like to have the iMac just as the display output of my MacBook Pro. Is that possible?

A very stupid solution is to use TeamViewer, however the display effect is quite bad.

Model of the Macs:

1. MacBook Pro `15-inch, 2016`
2. iMac `iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2014)`

Comment: Please research [Target Display Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592)

Comment: Web based screen sharing services are SLOW, as you have discovered. Have you tried Apple's built-in screen sharing? Failing that Target display mode might be an available option, like @Allan mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately target display mode was removed starting with your iMac model.

You could use the built in screen sharing function if your computers are on the same network.

On MacBook
System preferences -> sharing -> check of “screen sharing”

On iMac
- Open finder
- Under network in your left sidebar, you should see your MacBook
- Click on this
- Just under the top menu bar you should see “share screen”
- Click this, and a prompt will ask you for a username and password
- Enter credentials for your MacBook use account
Viola! Latency should be pretty minimal for this, and you can even control your MacBook this way!

Comment: Wow. this is cool. Thanks for the tip and I am using this way to reply to you. However, the latency is not very fixed. Sometimes it's very small, sometimes it's big.

Comment: It's not asking me the passwords. Is it because I am using the same Apple ID on both Mac?

Comment: You are very welcome! The latency may depend on your network load and type of connection. I would hardwire both of available. You are correct with you assumption regarding the non-requirement of credentials when the devices have the same Apple ID

Answer (score 0):

Screen Mirroring to Mac can also be accomplished with the AirPlay Receiver feature available since macOS Monterey 12 (late 2021). As of macOS Sonoma 14, the preference can be found at:

System Settings > General > AirDrop & Handoff > AirPlay Receiver

"AirPlay Receiver allows nearby Apple devices to send video and audio content to your Mac with AirPlay"

Apple Support document:
[Set up your Mac to be an AirPlay Receiver](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-up-your-mac-to-be-an-airplay-receiver-mchleee00ec8/mac)